recursive substitution on tree/term
Below I define tree-like terms with variables, which are to be replaced with terms in a method substitution.
I have two attempts, which both compile but produce an incorrect result.
Besides these two attempts, I saw a binary tree implementation using RC<RefCell<T>> for the child nodes but I could not apply it successfully and I am not sure if it should be used anyway.
attempt1
Since the mapping (v,t) is removed, only the first variable v is replaced.
I tried to use valuation.get (allowing the valuation to not be mutable), but this gives me a reference to a term.
Then dereferencing this reference does not work and cloning/copying seems to also not work.
use std::collections::{HashMap};
use std::hash::{Hash};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Term {
    Variable(u32),
    Operation(u32, Vec<Term>),
}

impl Term {
    fn substitute(self: Term, valuation: &mut HashMap<u32, Term>) -> Term {
        match self {
            Term::Variable(v) => {
                match valuation.remove(&v) {
                    None => { self } // variable not mapped by valuation
                    Some(t) => { t } // variable replaced according to valuation
                }
            }
            Term::Operation(op, args) => {
                // apply substitute recursively
                let mut updated: Vec<Term> = Vec::new();
                for t in args {
                    updated.push(t.substitute(valuation))
                }
                Term::Operation(op, updated)
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_bad_add() {
        let term = Term::Operation(1, vec![Term::Variable(2), Term::Variable(2)]);
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert(2, Term::Operation(3, vec![]));
        let result = term.substitute(&mut map);
        println!("{:?}", result);
        // prints: Operation(1, [Operation(3, []), Variable(2)])
        // expected: Operation(1, [Operation(3, []), Operation(3, [])])
    }
}

attempt2
Here I tried to emulate a dereferencing approach I saw elsewhere but (at least) the recursive part does not work as
use std::collections::{HashMap};
use std::hash::{Hash};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Term {
    Variable(u32),
    Operation(u32, Vec<Term>),
}

impl Term {
    fn substitute(self: &mut Term, valuation: &mut HashMap<u32, Term>) -> () {
        match self {
            Term::Variable(v) => {
                match valuation.remove(&v) {
                    None => { () } // variable not mapped by valuation
                    Some(t) => { *self=t } // variable replaced according to valuation
                }
            }
            Term::Operation(op, args) => {
                // apply substitute recursively
                let mut updated: Vec<Term> = Vec::new();
                for t in args {
                    (*t).substitute(valuation)
                }
                *self=Term::Operation(*op, updated)
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_bad_add() {
        let mut term = Term::Operation(1, vec![Term::Variable(2), Term::Variable(2)]);
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert(2, Term::Operation(3, vec![]));
        let result =  term.substitute(&mut map);
        println!("{:?}", term);
        // prints: Operation(1, [])
        // expected: Operation(1, [Operation(3, []), Operation(3, [])])
    }
}


The error comes from the fact that you remove an assignment while reading it (the method you call is named remove, so it's not that surprising...), so the second time you try to read the assignment for the variable 2, there isn't one anymore. Replace remove with get to make it work.
use std::collections::{HashMap};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
enum Term {
    Variable(u32),
    Operation(u32, Vec<Term>),
}

impl Term {
    fn substitute(self: Term, valuation: &HashMap<u32, Term>) -> Term {
        match self {
            Term::Variable(v) => {
                match valuation.get(&v) {
                    None => { self } // variable not mapped by valuation
                    Some(t) => { t.clone() } // variable replaced according to valuation
                }
            }
            Term::Operation(op, args) => {
                // apply substitute recursively
                let mut updated: Vec<Term> = Vec::new();
                for t in args {
                    updated.push(t.substitute(valuation))
                }
                Term::Operation(op, updated)
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_bad_add() {
        let term = Term::Operation(1, vec![Term::Variable(2), Term::Variable(2)]);
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert(2, Term::Operation(3, vec![]));
        let result = term.substitute(&mut map);
        assert_eq!(result, Term::Operation(1, vec![Term::Operation(3, Vec::new()), Term::Operation(3, Vec::new())]));[])])
    }
}

See it on the playground.
This solution does involve cloning the terms when subtituting a variable, but that is inevitable in your setting, as terms own their subterms, and the same term is used twice for a substitution.
